# What method can I use for categorical data to get unique values, mode and number of Null values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[here I tried to get unique values for each column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whqOm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whqOm.png)

I need to output the number of unique values, the mode and the number of Null values for categorical data.
If the '.describe' method works for interval data, then which method is relevant for categorical data?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print(df[['Class', 'Name']].nunique())
print(df[['Class', 'Name']].mode())
print(df[['Class', 'Name']].isna().sum())
```